# how do I clear the state of a prop in initial render of a page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a user Message component that I use for different pages. The problem I am facing is when a user message for one page is set, it doesn't reset for the other pages.

```
{this.props.statusMessage.messageType === 'service-error' && (
                        <UserMessage
                            className="alert"
                            messageText={this.props.statusMessage.userMessage}
                            messageType={this.props.statusMessage.messageType}
                            clearMessage={this.props.clearMessage}
                        />
                    )}
```

Any suggestions on what I could do?

Comment: what do you mean reset for the other pages?

Comment: I think your problem has more to do with the way you are saving the message text. Can you describe how you're doing that? are you using a redux store, or some sort of global variable? Is your intention to have a single global message, or multiple instances of different messages?

Comment: Hi koo,
What I mean by reset for the other pages is the following: 
1. I have a navbar that has two tabs. I have generic error messages that I am trying to reuse for the different pages. 
2. When I get an error message on one page, it is showing on the other page as well even if there is not supposed to be an error message on the other.

Comment: I am using a reducer to save the message and then connect it to the store